# How to trigger a click event of a button with javascript on an arbitrary site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, plugins

I need to navigate through a particular website, frequently, to get at some sub-page that is several layers beyond the front page and it is taking too much time to click and scroll and click and scroll to get at the desired final screen where I enter the search string.  So, I would like to automate the process by making Javascript trigger the right button events to get me to the distant page where I can enter the search string manually.

So, I know how the code needed to trigger the event,

```
document.getElementById('x').click();
```

but how can I implement this inside my browser, since this is not my own website?

Comment: From the console while you're on the site.

Comment: Or just install Selenium (or equivalent) plugin to your browser and record the annoying clicks, then play the test case whenever you want to get back to the desired screen.

Comment: javascipt:document.getElementById('x').click(); in the url bar. You can probably make a bookmarklet for it as well.

Comment: t0mppa Unable to install Selenium, but it sounds great on paper...  Any advice???

Answer (score 0):

If this is going thru different pages, then probably a Web UI automation tool would be the best (like Selenium - http://www.seleniumhq.org).

as @elcarns says, if you need to inject code into another's website, you could do so opening the console (view --> developers --> javascript console in Chrome).

Another, more complex way to do it when you have to traverse several pages is by developing a plugin.

Comment: Diego Pamio  I never developed a plugin.  But I would like that.  How can a plugin give you access?  Would it be something like Document.parent.(another document ref).bla...blah?

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:document.getElementById('x').click();` in the url bar. You can probably make a bookmarklet for it as well.

Comment: jameslafferty  This is rather interesting.  can I put in more than one line of Javascript code in the URL???

Comment: Sure... separate with semicolons. Btw, don't go cut and pasting JavaScript into your url if you don't know what it means, or you'll find all your Facebook friends hating your for spamming them.